# Converting SQL query to Sequelize ORM returns unwanted result

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, join, sequelize.js

I am a beginner to Sequelize and the concept of ORMs altogether. I have successfully converted my query to Sequelize findAll() function but it returns unwanted result. The PostgreSQL query works and returns the result perfectly fine.

Tables with Relationships:

1. writers(writerId PK, writerName)
2. posts(postId PK, postTitle, postDescription)
3. skillmatrix(skillmatrixId PK, writerId FK, postId FK, writerSkill)

My query:

```
SELECT writers."writerName", posts."postTitle", posts."postDescription", 
skillmatrix.* 
FROM writers
INNER JOIN skillmatrix
      ON writers."writerId" = skillmatrix."writerId"
INNER JOIN posts
      ON skillmatrix."postId" = posts."postId"
      ORDER BY writers."writerId", posts."postId"
```

Output from SQL Query:

[image]

Relations in Sequelize:

```
db.skillmatrix.hasMany(db.posts,{foreignKey: 'postId'});
db.skillmatrix.hasMany(db.writers,{foreignKey: 'writerId'});
```

findAll() method in Sequelize:

```
exports.findAll = (req, res, next) => {
SkillMatrix.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Writer,
            required: true
        },
        {
            model: Post, 
            required: true
        }
    ],
    order:[
        ['"writerId"', 'ASC'],
        ['"postId"', 'ASC']
    ]
})
.then(skillmatrix => {
    res.status(200).json(skillmatrix);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({msg: "error", details: err});
});
};
```

JSON output from Sequelize:

```
{
    "skillMatrixId": 1,
    "writerId": 1,
    "postId": 1,
    "writerSkill": "None",
    "writers": [
        {
            "writerId": 1,
            "writerName": "Writer1"
        }
    ],
    "posts": [
        {
            "postId": 1,
            "postTitle": "Post1"
            "postDescription": "This is Post1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "skillMatrixId": 2,
    "writerId": 1,
    "postId": 2,
    "writerSkill": "SEO",
    "writers": [
        {
            "writerId": 2,
            "writerName": "Writer2"  //This is unexpected
        }
    ],
    "posts": [
        {
            "postId": 2,
            "postTitle": "Post2",
            "postDescription": "This is Post2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "skillMatrixId": 3
    "writerId": 1,
    "postId": 3,
    "writerSkill": "Proofread"
    "writers": [
        {
            "writerId": 3,  //Unexpected
            "writerName": "Writer3" 
        }
    ],
    "posts": [
        {
            "postId": 3,
            "postTitle": "Post3",
            "postDescription": "This is Post3"
        }
    ]
}...
```

Kindly let me know, what am I doing wrong. Also suggest me some good resources where I can learn this in deep. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Sequelize log query:

```
SELECT "skillmatrix"."skillMatrixId", 
"skillmatrix"."writerId", "skillmatrix"."postId",
"skillmatrix"."writerSkill", 
"writers"."writerId" AS "writers"."writerId",  
"writers"."writerName" AS "writers"."writerName", 
"posts"."postId" AS "posts"."postId", 
"posts"."postTitle" AS "posts"."postTitle", 
"posts"."postDescription" AS "posts"."postDescription", 
"posts"."writerId" AS "posts"."writerId"
FROM "skillmatrix" AS "skillmatrix" 
INNER JOIN "writers" AS "writers" ON "skillmatrix"."skillMatrixId" = 
"writers"."writerId" 
INNER JOIN "posts" AS "posts" ON "skillmatrix"."skillMatrixId" = 
"posts"."postId" 
ORDER BY "skillmatrix"."writerId" ASC, "skillmatrix"."postId" ASC
```

Comment: The order by is done after the entire from, so your indentation is not reflecting the meaning. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Noted. Thanks. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Sequelize relation from :

```
db.skillmatrix.hasMany(db.posts,{foreignKey: 'postId'});
db.skillmatrix.hasMany(db.writers,{foreignKey: 'writerId'});
```

to:

```
db.skillmatrix.hasMany(db.posts,{sourceKey: 'postId' , foreignKey: 'postId'});
db.skillmatrix.hasMany(db.writers,{sourceKey: 'writerId' ,foreignKey: 'writerId'});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should examine the sequelize log - what query is generated by your findAll?  I'd guess it's joining on a wrong field.

Sequelize has some options for many-to-many relationships.  You might try:

```
db.posts.belongsToMany  (db.writers, {as : 'p2w', through: db.skillMatrix, foreignKey: 'postId'   });
db.writers.belongsToMany(db.posts,   {as : 'w2p', through: db.skillMatrix, foreignKey: 'writerId' });

db.posts.findAll({
  include: { 
     model: db.writers, 
     as: 'p2w',
     required: true
   }
});
```

I'm approximating the syntax - check it out in the doc: [belongsToMany](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)

Edit - your existing association can be fixed as follows:

```
db.skillmatrix.hasMany(db.writers,{sourceKey: 'writerId', foreignKey: 'writerId'});
```

But, keep in mind the M:M options for future tasks :)

Comment: Hello @KenOn10. Thanks for your answer, but is there any way I can do it without relating posts & writers?

Comment: I've added findAll query generated by sequelize log. Kindly check the question again.

Comment: You may have further problems if you leave your associations as is... 
That said, the generated SQL clearly shows the problem:  `INNER JOIN "writers" ON "skillmatrix"."skillMatrixId" = 
"writers"."writerId" ` but you need to use skillmatrix.writerId instead.    Try changing to `db.skillmatrix.hasMany(db.writers,{sourceKey: 'writerId', foreignKey: 'writerId'});`

Comment: It works like charm.. Kindly update your answer so I can Accept it. Thanks for your time.